# Generate and classify rows with 15 minutes time interval for a given time of the day

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, time

I already have a column called 'TimeOfDay' in the table which holds a time with an increment of a min like 02:01:00,02:02:00,02:03:00,02:04:00 and so on, I wanted to add a new column called '15MinuteSpan' which should classify the TimeOfDay in 15 min span interval.

For Example, if TimeOfday - 02:01:00 then 15MinuteSpan column should display 2:00-2:15 ,
If TimeOfday - 02:16:00 then 15MinuteSpan column should display 2:15-2:30 and so on.

Data in '15MinuteSpan' should look like as in the screen shot attached.

Any quick help is really appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5jlD.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work (assuming TimeOfDay is `TIME` data type, otherwise you will need to convert).  Rolling this into a computed column probably makes the most sense.

```
SELECT
  FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,-1*DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,TimeOfDay),'hh\:mm') + ' - ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,15-DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,TimeOfDay),'hh\:mm')
```

If you want the intervals not to overlap (14:00 - 14:14, 14:15 - 14:29, etc) then you would just need to change it to

```
SELECT
  FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,-1*DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,TimeOfDay),'hh\:mm') + ' - ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,14-DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,TimeOfDay),'hh\:mm')
```

Do note that "24:00" is not a displayed value for `TIME`, if you want something like `23:45 - 24:00` you'd have to break apart the hour and minutes and stitch things together from there.

Test code:

```
DECLARE @time TIME;

SET @time = '01:00:00.000' --Should return 01:00 - 01:15

SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,-1*DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm') + ' - ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,15-DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm')

SET @time = '01:00:00.001' --Should return 01:00 - 01:15

SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,-1*DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm') + ' - ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,15-DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm')

SET @time = '01:14:59.999' --Should return 01:00 - 01:15

SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,-1*DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm') + ' - ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,15-DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm')

SET @time = '01:15:00.000' --Should return 01:15 - 01:30

SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,-1*DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm') + ' - ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,15-DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm')

SET @time = '13:45:00.000' --Should return 13:45 - 14:00

SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,-1*DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm') + ' - ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,15-DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm')

SET @time = '13:45:00.001' --Should return 13:45 - 14:00

SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,-1*DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm') + ' - ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,15-DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm')

SET @time = '14:00:00.000' --Should return 14:00 - 14:15

SELECT FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,-1*DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm') + ' - ' + FORMAT(DATEADD(minute,15-DATEPART(minute,@time)%15,@time),'hh\:mm')
```

Comment: Thank you @bbaird, this code worked like a charm, it displays 15 min span correctly and accurately for the given TimeofDay.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just rounding down the time to 15 minute increments as:

```
select convert(time,
               dateadd(minute, (datepart(minute, timeofday) / 15) * 15,
                       dateadd(hour, datepart(hour, timeofday), 0
                      )
                              )
              ) as quarter_hour_start
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon, the data looks like:

TimeOfDay


01:28:00
01:29:00
01:30:00
01:31:00



quarter_hour_start


01:15:00.0000000
01:15:00.0000000
01:30:00.0000000
01:30:00.0000000


i.e for TimeOfday 01:27:00 , quarter_hour_start is 01:15:00.0000000
and for TimeOfday 01:34:00, quarter_hour_start is 01:30:00.0000000

But I need to display quarter_hour_start as below

i.e for TimeOfday 01:27:00 , quarter_hour_start should be 01:15 - 01:30
and for TimeOfday 01:34:00, quarter_hour_start should  be 01:30 - 01:45

any quick around to achieve this?

Comment: There is an logic we are using for MinuteSpan after con-catting with two columns where MinuteEndTime holds data as 

01:22:00
01:23:00
01:24:00
01:25:00
01:26:00
01:27:00

and 

TimeOfDay as

01:21:00
01:22:00
01:23:00
01:24:00
01:25:00
01:26:00
\n




CAST(TimeOfDay AS char(5)) + ' - ' + CAST(MinuteEndTime AS char(5)) AS MinuteSpan

So, I guess we need two columns and then con-cat those columns to derive 15 min span data like 08:00 - 08:15 etc.